# Should I declare my Vector<> as a Vector<>*?

Tags: c++, pointers, stl

Suppose I'm writing a C++ staff management system with STL

I have an entity class called `StaffMember`:

```
class StaffMember
{
  //
}
```

and a repository called `Staff`:

```
class Staff
{
  private:
    std::vector<StaffMember> staffMembers;
}
```

How do I know if I should declare `staffMembers` as a `std::vector<StaffMember>` or `std::vector<StaffMember>*`?

As a pointer, I would need to delete it inside `~Staff()`, otherwise I would not.

Both will work, but the question is, which one do I choose and is there a general rule I can use when this question pops up in the future?

Comment: You said it yourself. The pointer is extra work (even beyond what you mentioned), and if you don't have a specific reason for using one, why would you do that extra work?

Comment: vector is all lowercase, editing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically by value (`std::vector<StaffMember>`), unless you need to share it. Even if you do need to share it, a smart pointer is much better than a raw pointer.

Compilation firewalls are an exception (e.g. PIMPL).

Answer (score 1):

I would use this:

```
// This means I have a vector (a list) of StaffMember pointers
std::vector<StaffMember *> myStaffMembers;

StaffMember *newStaffMember = new StaffMember();
myStaffMembers.push_back(newStaffMember);
```

Comment: Yes, I have pointers in the Vector - I realised that makes more sense just after I posted the question.

Comment: @user1002358, In the case of polymorphism, I suggest a vector of smart pointers.

Comment: hmm, I prefer std::vector<std::shared_ptr<StaffMember>> myStaffMembers;

Comment: It's not really a matter of "preferring" `shared_ptr`, it's a matter of correctness. =P The code here isn't exception-safe.

Comment: Why would you prefer to hold `StaffMember` pointers over values?

Comment: To benefit from polymorphism.